# Fetching data from API and displaying as Name and website link

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to fetch data from the API and display them in format `Name + clickable website link`.
I was able to display data but the link is represented as text rather than hyperlink.

There is my Ajax script:

```js
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
             console.log(data.name);


                for (i = 0; data.length; i++)  {
                    name = data[i].name;
                    web_pages = data[i].web_pages;


                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href', web_pages);
                    link.innerHTML = web_pages;


                        var paragraph = $("<p />", {
                          text: name + " " + link
                        });

                    $("#display-resources").append(paragraph);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can it be because you are appending the `paragraph` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're inserting the link as text (string). Try this instead

```
var paragraph = $("<p />", { text: name + " " }).append(link)
```

Comment: thanks! one quick question, how can I print link in the new line of the paragraph? thanks!